# RESTful Api authentication for an android app

Tags: android, json, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have an assignment where i need to use an email and password to authenticate a user and get an access token. I have both the api key, secret and the base URL. I am not required to use a redirect URL for the assignment and it wasn't provided. I am not sure which approach or which library to use. I am drowning in the abundance of information and it is confusing me. I need to be pointed in the right direction.... any kind of help will be welcome. Thanks

Comment: Are your requirement to use Oauth 1.0 or 2.0? It's hard to tell from your question. 1.0 uses a "consumer key" and "consumer secret" (so I'm thinking maybe 1.0), but it requires redirection (maybe not). 2.0 doesn't require redirection (ok good), but uses a "client id" and "client secret" (doesn't match requirement). Please clarify, for further help.

Comment: Check out the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3) from the OAuth 2.0 spec. I believe that is what the instruction requires. It shows an example token request, where the client id (api key... maybe) and client secret are base64 encoded into the Authorization header. You may want to clarify this with your instructor, or whoever gave you the assignment. Also see [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for how to properly formulate the Authorization header

Comment: the outline is below

Comment: For the purpose of this exercise, use the email/password flow outlined here to obtain a access token xxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Please note that the redirect_uri URL parameter is not required for this exercise, only username, password, client_id and client_secret. You do not have to care about the token expiring or take care of refreshing it for this assignment, you are only interested in the access_token part of the response.Once you get an access token for the user, any subsequent API call can be authenticated by setting the Authorization HTTP header to be OAuth2 <access_token>”.

Comment: Yes the links I provided are what you want to look at. usename and password are sent in the body as form-urlencoded data (along with the grant_type) and the `client_id:client_secret` (actual values of course) are Base64 encoded in the `Authorization` header. Please refer to the resource links I provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based off your comments, the instructions tells you to use [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3). You can see an [example request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2) in the spec.

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w
```

The only thing that may seem odd (if you've never encountered it), is the `Authorization` header value. Read up on [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Basically the `czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW` is a base64 encoding of `username:password` (actually `<client_id>:<client_secret>`).

Without using any outside libraries (just standard Java libs) to make the request, you might have something like

```
String formData = "username=<uname>&password=<pass>&grant_type=password";
String header = "Basic " + Base64.encodeAsString("<client_id>:<client_secret>");

HttpURLConnection connection
                = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(tokenUrl).openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", header);
connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(formData.length()));

OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
out.write(formData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
AccessToken token = new ObjectMapper().readValue(in, AccessToken.class);
System.out.println(token);

out.close();
in.close();
```

The `Base64` I used is not a standard library class. Also the `ObjectMapper` is not a standard library class. I just used it to parse the token response to the `AccessToken` class. You can use any parser you like. The `AccessToken` class just has all the possible token values

```
public class AccessToken {
    public String access_token;
    public String refresh_token;
    public long expires_in;
    public String token_type;
    public String scope;
}
```

From there, once you have the token, any resource requests you want to make, you just need to add an `Authorization` header with `Bearer <access_token>`.

Comment: This was very helpful! I am wondering which library did u use for the BASE64?

Comment: It's a class from a backend framework I was using. It had nothing to do with the test I did, but I just used the project so I didn't have to create another project for this simple test. The class will probably be of no use to you. Though it appears Android has a [Base64 class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) also. Oh and the last paragraph, I think it doesn't match your requirements. Looks like the auth scheme should be `OAuth2` instead of `Bearer`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use the [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library to do that.

Let's say your URL base is http://baseurl.com/api and you have to perform a GET request to /login passing the email and password. I am assuming that your API will return a User object as JSON.

Api.java

```
public interface Api {

    @GET("/login")
    public void login(@Query("email") String email, @Query("password"), Callback<User> callback);

}
```

Where you need to perform the API call:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("http://baseurl.com")
    .build();

Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
api.login(email, password, new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void success(User user, Response response) {
        // login logic
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        Log.e("Retrofit", error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

I hope this example can help you. Don't forget to read the [retrofit documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: I tried this it isn't working. Retrofit simple too easy to be true yet... it doesn't work for me.

Comment: For the purpose of this exercise, use the email/password flow outlined here to obtain a access token xxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Please note that the redirect_uri URL parameter is not required for this exercise, only username, password, client_id and client_secret. You do not have to care about the token expiring or take care of refreshing it for this assignment, you are only interested in the access_token part of the response.Once you get an access token for the user, any subsequent API call can be authenticated by setting the Authorization HTTP header to be OAuth2 <access_token>”.